# Socket.io client behavior when server is unreachable

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I was wondering what is the default behavior when socket.io-client can't connect to the server and no callback is provided on the error.

Does the client indefinitely try to reconnect until it can reach the server?

I noticed that If I run this code on client before launching the server. As soon as the latter is started it receives the 'doSomethig' evnt.

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('doSomething', data);
    socket.destroy();
});
```

How can I prevent the server to receive data emitted before it was started?

Comment: I realize that the question may be a bit silly but I'm quite new to event based programming

Comment: You can just discard the data, or write client-side code to stop attempting to reconnect and send/store data until connection is established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
socket.on('connect_error', function () { socket.destroy(); });
```